# Error "incorrect syntax near if,then,else" please correct

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i am creating a function to calculate interest . dbo.days1() is a function which gives no of days

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.int1
    (

    )

RETURNS int
as
begin
declare @days int

set @days = dbo.days1()
if @days > 0 
then
return( select((((dbo.delivery.roi * dbo.delivery.adv1)/100)/365)*@days)from delivery)
    else
    return (0)
     end if      
    END
```

it gives me syntax error near if then and else.how to correct

Answer (score 1):

There is no `then` and `end if` part in a SQL `if..else` statement.
Reference [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms182717.aspx)

Your entire function can be rewritten into a single line to exclude the if and any other variables, it makes it a bit harder to read though:

```
create function dbo.int1 ()
  returns int
as
begin
  declare @days      int = dbo.days1(),
          @returnInt int = 0

  if @days > 0
  begin
    set @returnInt = (isnull((select((((dbo.delivery.roi * dbo.delivery.adv1)/100)/365)*dbo.days1())from delivery), 0))
  end

    return (@returnInt)
end
```

Comment: but i dont want negative value . if dbo.days1() returns a negative value then function dbo.int1() should return 0

Comment: Not sure why this answer was downvoted? Minuser, care to give a feedback on how to enhance this post?

Comment: The down vote came before I added the second part of my answer with the correct create function. The original first part was only the first two lines, which was answering the original question of why the syntax error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

why can't you try like below

```
    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.int1
    (

    )
    RETURNS int
    as
    begin
    declare @days int
    set @days = dbo.days1()
    if @days > 0 
    begin
        return( select((((dbo.delivery.roi * dbo.delivery.adv1)/100)/365)*@days)from delivery)
    end

    return (0)       
    end
```

Comment: it gives diff error "the last statement included within a function must be a return statement"

Comment: sorry, my intention was to remove the else condition but because of typo mistake i updated the code without removing else...

Comment: Even if one of the RETURN statements will be executed given the condition, but since the last statement is not a RETURN statement by itself and not within a condition, the following error "the last statement included within a function must be a return statement" will be raised

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.int1
    (

    )

RETURNS int
as
begin
declare @days int

set @days = dbo.days1()
if @days > 0 
 Begin
  return(select((((dbo.delivery.roi * dbo.delivery.adv1)/100)/365)*@days)from delivery)
 End

else
 Begin
   return (0)
 End

END
```